# Jquery not working in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

basically I have a JS code so that when I click on the image a html file is displayed on the same page, however it is displayed but in another page and I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).load(...).fail is not a function
```

View::

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Best programmer ever')
@section('content')
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/js/template.js')}}" rel="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
@endsection
        @section('template')
        <!--     @foreach ($templates as $template)
           {{$template->image}}
            {{$template->file}}
        @endforeach
        -->
        <div class= "template_class">
        <a class="content-link" href="{{ asset($template->file )}}"> 
        <img id = "image" src="{{ asset($template->image )}}"/>
  </a>
</div>
        @show


$(function(){
   $('.content-link').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $('.content').load(this.href)
                    .fail(function(){ alert('Oops...something went wrong');});
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

seems that `fail` is not a function, try handling error this way:

```
$( ".content" ).load( this.ref, function( response, status, xhr ) {
  if ( status == "error" ) {
    alert("Oops...something went wrong";
  }
});
```

Comment: that just completelly doesn't work, function has got arguments but they are never used

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas try updating your jQuery version to 1.12.4, take a look of this http://www.w3schools.com/JQuery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load_callback